# Exercise with XMLTABLE e XML in SQL table

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

i am trying to solve this exercise but I'm not able to find the correct solution.

Get from the table matchRound the information about the teams will play in the third round. In the third round will play the best team played in the first round against the best team in the second round.
The general rules for access to the third round are:

1. Having won the highest number of match
2. In case of equal, wins the team that scored the last goal
3. In case of equal ,wins the home team

This is the table:

```
CREATE TABLE matchRound (
 round_num INTEGER,
 play_date DATE,
 home_team CHAR(2),
 visiting_team CHAR(2),
 goals XMLTYPE,
 PRIMARY KEY(play_date, home_team)
);


INSERT INTO matchRound VALUES (1, TO_DATE('1/1/2012', 'DD/MM/YYYY'), 'MI', 'IN', xmltype.createxml('<?xml version="1.0"?><goals><player team="MI" minute="62">De Rossi</player><player team="MI" minute="25">Pirlo</player></goals>'));
INSERT INTO matchRound VALUES (1, TO_DATE('2/1/2012', 'DD/MM/YYYY'), 'MI', 'GE', xmltype.createxml('<?xml version="1.0"?><goals><player team="MI" minute="30">De Rossi</player><player team="GE" minute="25">Cannavaro</player></goals>'));
INSERT INTO matchRound VALUES (1, TO_DATE('3/1/2012', 'DD/MM/YYYY'), 'IN', 'GE', xmltype.createxml('<?xml version="1.0"?><goals></goals>'));
INSERT INTO matchRound VALUES (2, TO_DATE('4/1/2012', 'DD/MM/YYYY'), 'TO', 'JU', xmltype.createxml('<?xml version="1.0"?><goals><player team="JU" minute="40">Gattuso</player><player team="JU" minute="90">Rossi</player></goals>'));
INSERT INTO matchRound VALUES (2, TO_DATE('5/1/2012', 'DD/MM/YYYY'), 'TO', 'SM', xmltype.createxml('<?xml version="1.0"?><goals><player team="TO" minute="20">Gialli</player><player team="TO" minute="30">Neri</player><player team="TO" minute="50">Verdi</player></goals>'));
INSERT INTO matchRound VALUES (2, TO_DATE('6/1/2012', 'DD/MM/YYYY'), 'JU', 'SM', xmltype.createxml('<?xml version="1.0"?><goals><player team="JU" minute="20">Gattuso</player><player team="JU" minute="40">Rossi</player></goals>'));
```

This is a part of my solution:

```
SELECT T1.round_num, T1.win, count(T1.win) as "GOALS"
FROM (
  SELECT PG.round_num, PG.home_team AS "home", V.win
  FROM matchRound PG,
  XMLTABLE('let $x := //player[@team=$s1]
      let $y := //player[@team=$s2]
      let $z := //player
      return if(count($x)=count($y)) then <win>{data($z[last()]/@team)}</win>
      else if(count($x)>=count($y)) then <win>{$s1}</win>
      else <win>{$s2}</win>'
    PASSING PG.goals, PG.home_team AS "s1", PG.visiting_team AS "s2"
    COLUMNS
      win VARCHAR2(255) PATH '/win'
  ) V
) T1
GROUP BY T1.round_num, T1.win
ORDER BY T1.round_num;
```

Can you help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main problem I can see with your XPath is the use of `last()`; that assumes the goals are in the order they were scored, which isn't the case. In the first match the node for the 62nd-minute is before the one for the 25th-minute goal. You also aren't handling the no-score-draw situation, which you have in the third match.

Pulling the XML data out in a different format to make it more readable:

```
 ROUND_NUM PLAY_DATE  HO VI HOME_GOALS HOME_MIN   AWAY_GOALS AWAY_MIN   LAST_GOAL
---------- ---------- -- -- ---------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ----------
         1 2012-01-01 MI IN          2 25,62               0            MI        
         1 2012-01-02 MI GE          1 30                  1 25         MI        
         1 2012-01-03 IN GE          0                     0                    
         2 2012-01-04 TO JU          0                     2 40,90      JU        
         2 2012-01-05 TO SM          3 20,30,50            0            TO        
         2 2012-01-06 JU SM          2 20,40               0            JU
```

Adjusting the XPath, and changing the names to make them a bit more meaningful, you can get:

```
select mr.round_num, mr.play_date, mr.home_team, mr.visiting_team, x.win,
  count(x.win) over (partition by mr.round_num, x.win) as wins
from matchround mr
cross join xmltable('let $hg := //player[@team=$h]
    let $vg := //player[@team=$v]
    let $lhgm := max(//player[@team=$h]/@minute)
    let $lvgm := max(//player[@team=$v]/@minute)
    return if(count($hg)>count($vg)) then <win>{$h}</win>
      else if(count($vg)>count($hg)) then <win>{$v}</win>
      else if($lhgm>$lvgm) then <win>{$h}</win>
      else if($lvgm>$lhgm) then <win>{$v}</win>
      else <win>{$h}</win>'
  passing mr.goals, mr.home_team as "h", mr.visiting_team as "v"
  columns
    win varchar2(10) path '/win'
) x
order by round_num, play_date, home_team;

 ROUND_NUM PLAY_DATE  HO VI WIN              WINS
---------- ---------- -- -- ---------- ----------
         1 2012-01-01 MI IN MI                  2
         1 2012-01-02 MI GE MI                  2
         1 2012-01-03 IN GE IN                  1
         2 2012-01-04 TO JU JU                  2
         2 2012-01-05 TO SM TO                  1
         2 2012-01-06 JU SM JU                  2
```

`$lhgm` and `$lvgm` are the last home/visitor goal minute, from the maximum value of those. (Not sure if they need to be explicitly converted to numbers first though; this works for the given data, but check with a single-digit minute). The `wins` value is an analytic count of the number of wins for each team.

You can then see which has the greatest number of wins:

```
select round_num, max(win) keep (dense_rank last order by wins) as team
from (
  select mr.round_num, mr.play_date, mr.home_team, x.win,
    count(x.win) over (partition by mr.round_num, x.win) as wins
  from matchround mr
  cross join xmltable('let $hg := //player[@team=$h]
      let $vg := //player[@team=$v]
      let $lhgm := max(//player[@team=$h]/@minute)
      let $lvgm := max(//player[@team=$v]/@minute)
      return if(count($hg)>count($vg)) then <win>{$h}</win>
        else if(count($vg)>count($hg)) then <win>{$v}</win>
        else if($lhgm>$lvgm) then <win>{$h}</win>
        else if($lvgm>$lhgm) then <win>{$v}</win>
        else <win>{$h}</win>'
    passing mr.goals, mr.home_team as "h", mr.visiting_team as "v"
    columns
      win varchar2(10) path '/win'
  ) x
)
group by round_num
order by round_num;

 ROUND_NUM TEAM     
---------- ----------
         1 MI        
         2 JU
```

Comment: Thank you so much , I did not know the function "keep", "over" and "partition by" they are provided by the sql standard ? or are functions of Oralce ?

Comment: Not sure quite what is standard to be honest; these are supported by SQL Server too I believe, but I only work with Oracle. You can read more about [analytic functions](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/functions004.htm) and [keep last](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/functions083.htm)/[first](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/functions065.htm) in the Oracle docs though.